# Hanami link_to helper renders only last element

Tags: ruby, hanami

i'm new in the Hanami World.
I'have write this code:

```
module Web::Views::Home
  class Index
    include Web::View
    include Hanami::Helpers::HtmlHelper

    def title
      html.header do
        h1 'Test search engine', id: 'title'
        hr
        div(id: 'test') do
          link_to('Home', "/", class: 'mnu_orizontal')
          link_to('About', "/", class: 'mnu_orizontal')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I call `title` method on the template.
The html result is:

```
<header>
    <h1 id="title">Test search engine</h1>
    <hr>
    <div id="test">
        <a class="mnu_orizontal" href="/">About</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Why the second link overwrite the first? Where is my error?

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's the [expected behaviour](https://github.com/hanami/helpers/issues/48) for the current version of `hanami/helpers` (v0.3.0).

As jodosha wrote on the issue linked above:

> After a deeper looking at this issue, it isn't a bug.
>   `link_to` doesn't work like the other HTML builder methods. That means you can avoid to concat tags.

The next version (v0.4.0) will allow to concat `link_to`, see this [PR](https://github.com/hanami/helpers/pull/52).

So it's not your fault, but I think the [documentation](http://hanamirb.org/guides/helpers/html5/#other-helpers) is out of sync, it already shows the [new version](https://github.com/hanami/hanami.github.io/pull/145/files).

Hope it helps! Bye.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, i have edit my code:

```
module Web::Views::Home
  class Index
    include Web::View
    include Hanami::Helpers::HtmlHelper

    def title
      html.header do
        h1 'Global search engine (GSearch)', id: 'title'
        hr
        div(id: 'test') do
          ul do
            li (link_to('Home', "/", class: 'mnu_orizontal'))
            li (link_to('About', "/", class: 'mnu_orizontal'))
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can concat together the two `link_to` with `#+`. See this example: https://github.com/hanami/helpers/pull/52/files#diff-6a0d85bea58ea52c21a97cee6e67cad0R579